# CakePHP how to automatically include 3rd level relationship on one field?

Tags: php, cakephp

In short, `Users` have many `Posts`, which have and belong to many `Tags`.

Also, `Users` have many `Recipes`, which have and belong to many `Ingredients`.

```
$this->User->find('all'); // Yields one level, no associated Tags or Ingredients.
```

Adding:

```
$this->User->find('all', array('recursive' => 2); // Yields two levels, all Tags and Ingredients
```

What if I just want to recurse one field, namely `Recipe`, so I get all of the `Ingredients`?

It appears I want to use the [`contain`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) behavior, but this seems to have no effect. If I remove the `recursive` behavior I only get one level of data.

Also have this included in my model.

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Comment: You're correct that you should be using Containable instead of recursive. But it appears you just need to read the CakePHP book more thoroughly. It explains (in a LOT of detail) how to use [CakePHP's Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) including using the `contain()` array, setting recursive to -1...etc etc etc. Read through that, try again, and if it doesn't work, post the actual code that uses Containable.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but that was the first thing I did. That's why I'm here. I *think* I understand what each level of recursion does and *think* I understand what contain does, but I'm obviously overlooking something that isn't apparent to me in the docs.

Comment: don't use $recursive.  Set it to -1 in the AppModel, and don't change it again.  I promise it will save you many many headaches further down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) Behavior as below.

```
$this->User->find('all', array('contain' => 'Ingredient'));
```

Though if you already used `recursive` , and if you wish to remove all post data, a quick solution is to `unbind` your post model as like below.

```
$this->User->unbindModel(
    array('hasMany' => array('Post'))
);
$this->User->find('all', array('recursive' => 2);
```

Comment: Unbinding the relations from the model works for me! However, why doesn't the first answer using `contain` work for me? If I use your first answer with or without contain, I only retrieve one level of data. (So I'm not getting the Ingredients). I want the second level with the Ingredients, but this isn't working with contain. Thoughts?

Comment: `$recursive` of anything other than `-1` is a bad idea and will cause issues as you get more data in your database and/or expand your project.